# set mailto default handler in chrome with javascript

Tags: google-chrome, gmail

I want to set mailto default handler in chrome with javacript. Is there any way to do this.
For example my default handler is Outlook and I want to change it to Gmail with a javascript program.

Comment: Good grief, I hope not...or if it can be done, I *really*,*really* hope that it requires a user-confirmation =/

Answer (score 4):

> While in Gmail, copy and paste the following into your browser's address bar and hit enter.

```
javascript:window.navigator.registerProtocolHandler("mailto","https://mail.google.com/mail/?extsrc=mailto&url=%s","Gmail")
```

http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2008/07/power-tip-set-gmail-as-your-default.html